# Can I use jQuery to do $_GET method/look at file's url

Tags: jquery, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

I am writing a jQuery function that saves an item remotely with Ajax. I'd like to be able to grab the `edit.php?id=###&field=###` info from the url right in my function. How would I do that?

Comment: this post explains how to do it [get-query-string-values-in-javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this task, you can do it simply with javascript :

```
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
     return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

Then if you retrieve this url : http://www.yoursite.com/Index.php?g=12&param=43
to retrieve the 'param' parameter, all you need to do is this :

```
var param_value = gup('param');
```

or the 'g' parameter like this :

```
var param_value = gup('g');
```

or switch 'param' with the name of the parameter you need.