# PHP & Javascript Ajax : how to get URL data when our method is "GET"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I checked the following questions in case this is a duplicate, but they do not answer my question:

[get-data-from-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194280/get-data-from-url)

[how-can-i-get-query-string-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

[can-i-use-jquery-to-do-get-method-look-at-files-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234678/can-i-use-jquery-to-do-get-method-look-at-files-url)

Those questions is about retrieve url by javascript. In this case is in PHP.

```
goServer({
    url: 'checkuser.php?name='+name+'&password' + psw,
    method: 'GET'
});
```

Everything goes fine, response fine. Except when in the target file (checkuser.php):

```
$name = $_GET['name']'; (also for other params)
```

it occurs error/warning that there is no index 'name' or 'password' in the $_GET variables.

Question: how to get URL data when ajax method is "GET" ?

Thank you

(OH MY.. Stupid error. It sent in `GET` but written in target file `$_POST['name']`)

Comment: can you post results of `print_r($_GET)`

Comment: don't delete questions it affects you negatively.

Comment: Don't delete questions, others can learn from it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be this:

```
goServer({
    url: 'checkuser.php?name='+name+'&password=' + psw,
    method: 'GET'
});
```

> `$name = $_GET['name'];`

Comment: your answer has part of his question

Comment: I forgot to check source in my file. The stupid is, it sent by GET, by i receive by POST.. Oh my,,

Answer (score 2):

do both fail? You need "password=" not just "password" in your URL

also you have an extra ' in your GET statement. should be `$_GET['name'];`